# How to create/update a lead?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to SFDC. How can i create/update a lead using `Apex` ?

I tried;

```
@isTest 
private class TestClass {
    static testMethod void testLogic() {
        //Create new lead
       // insert new Lead(Company = 'Lead Company', FirstName = 'firstname', LastName = 'lastname', Email = 'some@gmail.com');

    }
}
```

Test case is successful but i could not see the record on SFDC UI on click of `Leads`. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running a test method all writes to DB doesn't affect your current DB (also unless specified you cant read current DB).

Running following line, in execute anonymous will create the lead:

```
   insert new Lead(Company = 'Lead Company', FirstName = 'firstname', LastName = 'lastname', Email = 'some@gmail.com');
```

Or just create a regular class and call its method from VF.